# Sending mails using mailkit nuget package doesn't work when project is published on azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, smtp, mailkit

I have problem with my .NET Core 3.1 app. I finished it and published on Azure.

App works as expected but when I try to send email (using the mailkit nuget package), I get an error 500.

Is there any way to enable connection between azure and mail server?

Here are server and port I'm using to connect to server

```
SmtpSettings": {
    "ServerAddress": "smtp.live.com",
    "Port": "587"
},
```

I believe my implementation of code is not important in this question because sending mail works fine when app is tested locally.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with outlook!

It didn't proccess mails because server didn't want to accept login from unfamiliar device